# Can Flyway maintain two version tables for two different type of scripts?

Tags: flyway

I want to run two different scripts in one database.
How can i maintain two seperate versions for these scripts? We have such requirement because these two scripts belong to two different modules.and we have to run them different times.I need to implement this in API java.
Can anybody help me???

Answer (score 0):

Run Flyway twice, each time with a different setting for `flyway.table`. Just be aware that clean will not differentiate and clean the whole schema.